# How to get Brother PJ-623 working with Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I have a Brother PocketJet 6 Plus (model PJ-623) that I would like to use with Ubuntu. I am positive the printer works, as I can print to it fine from Windows. The brother website provides official drivers in a deb package, but they are only for the 32-bit version of Ubuntu.

I tried install doing a force install and it recognizes the printer correctly but all prints fail. They are not shown in the print queue as errored or stuck, but nothing comes out of the printer.

They also provide a source package, but I'm not sure how to use it or if it can be used on a 64-bit OS. Is it possible to get this printer working with 64-bit Ubuntu somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it turns out this printer can work with modern, 64-bit Ubuntu.

1. Go to printers in application menu and remove any existing PJ-623 entries.
2. Unplug PJ-623 from computer
3. In the terminal run the command `sudo mkdir /var/spool/lpd` (if it complains the directory already exists then that is fine)
4. Install the `lib32z1` package with `sudo apt install lib32z1`
5. Install the official Brother debs with `sudo dpkg -i --force-all /path/to/your/brother.deb`
6. Plug PJ-623 into your computer, it should now print.